# 3 Simple Queries SQL Student Question, Query Errors in Microsoft Access

Tags: query, ms-access, date, ms-access-2016

The First Question is: "List the name of each trip that does not start in New Hampshire (NH)."

```
SELECT TripName
FROM Trip
WHERE State!='NH'; /* works with State='NH' */
```

[image: errror1]

The Second Question is: "List the trip name, type, and maximum group size for all trips that have Susan Kiley as a guide."

```
SELECT TripName, MaxGrpSize
FROM Trip, TripGuides
WHERE Type=Hiking, GuideNum = 'BR01';
/* also i tried WHERE Type=Hiking AND GuideNum = 'BR01'; */
```

[image]

I Cant Filter by only type: "Hiking"

The Third Question is: List the reservation ID, customer number, customer last name, and customer first name for all trips that occur in July 2018.
I Tried This:|

```
SELECT DISTINCT  LastName, FirstName, CustomerNum, ReservationID
FROM Customer, Reservation
WHERE TripDate = '2018-12'; /* i tried CustomerNum.Customer */
```

[image]

If you need more tables and more information let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first is simple access  has no !=

```
SELECT TripName AS Ausdr1
FROM Trip
WHERE ([State])<>'NH';
```

the form of the second is wrong and you should start to use proper JOINs a comma for tables means always a CROSS JOIN, which can be useful, but nit in this case

also strings must `always` be in quotes

```
SELECT TripName , MaxGrpSize 
FROM Trip, TripGuides
WHERE ((([Type])='Hiking') AND (([GuideNum])='BR01'));
```

the last  us simple both tables have the column ´CustomerNum´, so you have to tell access which one you want, but i guess it is a joining column.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  LastName, FirstName, [Customer].CustomerNum, ReservationID
FROM Customer, Reservation
WHERE TripDate = '2018-12';
```

what i mean by proper joining:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  LastName, FirstName, c.CustomerNum, ReservationID
FROM Customer C INNER JOIN Reservation r ON c.CustomerNum = r.CustomerNum
WHERE TripDate = '2018-12';
```

I don't know your complete tables , so i am only guessing